# Dissolve line intersection in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have two lines

[image]

I want to disole where the two lines intersect to become like this

[image]

How to do that in QGIs 3.16?

---

I digitizing two streets. And I modify the width of the lines.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they are lines and not polygons?

Comment: Do you have only that one or many more?

Comment: Yes, this tho streets. They are Line and not poligone.

Comment: you do not want to dissolve your line you just want the border of your symbol not showing at intersection look at symbol level to learn how to do that (https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#symbol-levels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer` and use the following settings:

- Input layer: The line layer
- Distance: *half* the width of the road (you're buffering out from the middle)
- Segments: *default*
- End cap style: Flat
- Join style: *default*
- Miter limit: *default*
- Dissolve result: **Checked / Yes**

Comment: Thank you @TeddyTedTed, it's correct. But i see that it becomes one shape. Is it possible to only disolve the intersect ?

Comment: Is this just for display purposes or do you need a polygon of the intersection for analysis?